# How to override a property in a library's interface with an incompatible type?

Tags: typescript

I have a library which declares an interface.

```js
export interface Block {
    readonly type: BlockType
}

export enum BlockType {
    content = 'content',
    html = 'html',
    section = 'section',
}
```

That library wraps an API. However, when I use this API on a different project, I get different values in `type`, so I need to make a new `enum` and force-feed it to `Block`.

I need to override this interface so that its `type` parameter has an entirely different, incompatible type.

```js
declare module 'nice-lib' {
    export enum BlockType {
        article = 'article',
    }

    export interface Block {
        readonly type: BlockType
    }
}
```

However, I get this error:

> All declarations of 'Block' must have identical type parameters.

Which makes sense, but I do need to override it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to change the type of the type property, which is not allowed because the Block interface is defined as readonly, meaning that it can't be modified.

One way to solve this problem would be to create a new interface in your own project that extends the Block interface, but with a different type for the type property. Use the extends keyword and provide a new type for the type property. For example:

```
 import { Block, BlockType } from 'nice-lib'; 

    export enum MyBlockType {
    article = 'article',
    }

    export interface MyBlock extends Block {
    readonly type: MyBlockType;
    }
```

This will create a new interface, MyBlock, that extends the Block interface, but with a different type for the type property. You can then use the MyBlock interface in your own code, and the type property will be of type MyBlockType instead of BlockType.